# Why does T implement A+B but not trait C: A+B?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm puzzled by this example. Even though `i32` implements all of the `Num + One + Zero + PartialOrd + RemAssign + Ord`, when I put them into a trait so I can give an alias, it doesn't work.

```
use num_traits::{Num, identities::One, identities::Zero};
use std::cmp::{Ord, PartialOrd};
use std::ops::RemAssign;

pub trait Math: Num + One + Zero + PartialOrd + RemAssign + Ord {}

fn s<T: Num + One + Zero + PartialOrd + Ord + RemAssign>(t: T) {
    unimplemented!();
}

fn ss<T: Math>(t: T) {
    unimplemented!();
}

fn sss() {
    let x: i32 = 5;
    ss(x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1e89b889a7e5d8336b38cee20888454b)

Is there a way to force all the things that implement `Num + One + Zero + PartialOrd + RemAssign + Ord` to implement `Math`?

Comment: If your goal is to just support Rust's integer types, you can use `PrimInt` instead of `Num`. That will allow you to omit many (or even all) of those additional traits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by adding a blanket impl:

```rust
impl<T: Num + One + Zero + PartialOrd + RemAssign + Ord> Math for T {}
```