# Why the [u8] inside Box<[u8]> does not implement AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>?

Tags: rust

The code below creates a `Box<[u8]>`, which I though had a fixed size, because `Box` has a fixed size. Also, I though `[u8]` implemented `AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>`

```
pub trait MemAs<T>: AsMut<[T]> + AsRef<[T]> {}
fn allocate(size: usize) -> Box<dyn MemAs<u8>> {
    vec![0; size].into_boxed_slice()
}
```

Errors:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[{integer}]: MemAs<u8>` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     vec![0; size].into_boxed_slice()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `MemAs<u8>` is not implemented for `[{integer}]`
  |
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn MemAs<u8>`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[{integer}]` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     vec![0; size].into_boxed_slice()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `[{integer}]`
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn MemAs<u8>`
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a348e149773b8145284fac308666b220

What is wrong?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you never implemented the trait `MemAs`. `AsRef` and `AsMut` are implemented, but `MemAs` isn't. Do you want to add a blanket impl for `T: AsRef<[T]> + AsMut<[T]>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i32 implements A+B but not trait C: A+B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69916809/i32-implements-ab-but-not-trait-c-ab)

Answer (score 3):

First off, there are no `impl` blocks for `MemAs`. You probably meant to write a blanket impl:

```
impl<T, U> MemAs<T> for U
where
    U: AsMut<[T]> + AsRef<[T]> + ?Sized {}
```

`?Sized` is needed here because `[u8]` is unsized.

However, adding this impl reveals a much more serious problem:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u8]` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     vec![0; size].into_boxed_slice()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `[u8]`
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn MemAs<u8>`
```

This is saying you can't cast a `[u8]` to a `dyn MemAs<u8>`. A trait object (`dyn Thing`) can only refer to an object with a known size. `Box<[u8]>` is represented as a fat pointer (with the slice's length as auxiliary data), and `Box<dyn MemAs<u8>>` is also represented as a fat pointer (with a pointer to the vtable as auxiliary data), but there's no such thing as a "superfat" pointer in Rust (you can have a length or a vtable, but not both).

The workaround is to have two levels of `Box`:

```
fn allocate(size: usize) -> Box<dyn MemAs<u8>> {
    Box::new(vec![0; size].into_boxed_slice())
}
```

The function's body evaluates to a `Box<Box<[u8]>>`, which *can* be coerced to a `Box<dyn MemAs<u8>>` because `Box<[u8]>` implements `MemAs<u8>`. (The `?Sized` bound on the `impl` block is not needed for this to be true.)